# How to enforce periodic boundary conditions when performing regression with sci-kit learn?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, interpolation

I have signals that resemble sine waves (or, more accurately, sums of sines). The data are normalized in the time domain so that there is only one cycle and all of the points lie between 0 and 1. An example signal looks like this:

[image: Periodic signal]

I want to enforce that the prediction made at phase 0 is equal to that at phase 1. How can I do that while using the interpolation routines in scikit learn (e.g. the random forest regressor)?